# Designing table to store XML data in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, xml

I am planing to use SQL Server to store XML BLOBs for my application. I am struggling with a design decision, and looking for any guidelines or advice from someone experienced in this topic.

The data that needs to be stored as XML has about 100 simple data points. They can easily be categorized into groups of maybe 20 data points each. In future versions of application, we plan to increase the scope of the data by adding new data points, some of which will be hierarchical (lists, dictionaries, etc).

We are not anticipating needing to perform queries on the XML data. At most they will be very simple queries and we can promote any of the data points to a relational column if need be.

I am not sure whether I should just create one giant XML BLOB to hold all of this data, or if should break it down into multiple XML columns. Are there any best practices or guidelines for dealing with XML data type in SQL Server 2008 R2 that can help me make the best decision? Does it even matter?

EDIT: I am already set on using XML as a datatype, I am trying to make a decision on whether I should use one large BLOB or break it up into multiple XML columns.

Comment: Have you seen this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh403385.aspx

Comment: Mikael, I have read through this already.  However I'm still not sure about whether to break down my xml into multiple columns or just have one giant blob.  I understand there is a 2GB size limit, however I have no concerns about reaching that limit.  There is a section about XML granularity that I believe touches on my question, but to be honest I've read it multiple times and I still don't know which way to go.

Comment: If it logically makes sense to have one column for the XML then you should do just that. What is mentioned in the link about granularity has to do with the impact of splitting the XML on rows where a smaller part of the data is locked when updating. Using more columns does not have any effect on locking. The link also mentions optimizations when updating part of the XML both when you use XML indexes and when not so splitting on columns should not be much faster for updates.

Comment: Queries against smaller chunks will be faster but if you later on need to do queries over more than one column (using or) my guess is that the benefit from smaller chunks is lost. The best thing you can do for query performance is to use the selective XML indexes introduced in SQL Server 2012 SP1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it matters! When you store a large XML blob as `XML` datatype inside SQL Server, then it's not stored as a textual blob - it's "parsed" and "tokenized" and stored in a significantly more efficient manner than if you're using just `varchar(max)` to store the textual representation.

If it really looks like XML, smells like XML and quacks like XML - then **definitely USE** the `XML` datatype!

**Update:** if you only intend to store and retrieve the XML as a whole - I don't see any benefit in breaking it up into chunks. The `XML` datatype in SQL Server can hold up to **2 GByte** of data (just like `varchar(max)`) and you won't see any performance gains from storing (and retrieving) multiple smaller XML fragments.

Comment: It seems that question is not about `XML` vs string types, but rather _one giant XML_ vs _multiple [smaller] XML_

Comment: @DanLing: updated my response - if you only ever intend to store and retrieve the whole XML blob in a single operation - no point in having lots of small chunks....

Comment: Thanks Marc.  If I have to do updates on the data does that change things?  Sorry I failed to mention that from the beginning.

Comment: @DanLing: as long as you typically update the whole blob at once (just replace it with a new version), then no, that doesn't have any adverse effect on performance. If you start to replace only smaller chunks of it - then it could be an issue

Answer (score 0):

If the field is going to be used to store application payloads and the application can properly handle versioning or future modifications to the structure then I would go with an xml field. The only drawback to storing as xml is that queries can be more time consuming as opposed to flattened out data. If your apps handle all data being handed of as xml then this becomes a smaller hurdle to jump.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

It is recommendable to use nvarchar(MAX) to store XML. Since, If (near future) you plan to change it modify your storage to keep json(instead of xml), then it would be highly flexible to keep Json for you.
But if you chose to go for XML Datatype it is rigid to go only for XML. However, as Mark mentioned If it really looks like XML, smells like XML and quacks like XML - then definitely USE the XML datatype!
And if your business use case says to insert and retrieve the whole XML at once then I don't see there is much benefit of benefit in breaking it up into chunks on performance.